# Using python 2.7 regex to replace parts of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following line:

```
b = re.sub('^xMain (\S+)/y1,/y0 (\S+ )(.*)$', 'xMain \2\1\3', a)
```

where a is:

```
xMain Buchan/y1,/y0 Angus Sub1
```

Why does `b` come out as `'xMain \x02\x01\x03'`?
My intention is to de-invert a name. In Regexbuddy this works OK but not in Python 2.7.

Comment: It does not come out as "xMain". It comes out as "xMain" followed by a space followed by three unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

You see unprintable characters because `\2\1\3` have meaning in a *regular* python string too, as octal escape codes:

```
>>> '\2'
'\x02'
>>> 'xMain \2\1\3'
'xMain \x02\x01\x03'
```

They never make it to the `re.sub()` function as written.

Use a raw string literal instead:

```
b = re.sub('^xMain (\S+)/y1,/y0 (\S+ )(.*)$', r'xMain \2\1\3', a)
```

Note the `r'...'` string. In a raw string literal `\...` escape codes are not interpreted, leaving the back-references in place for the `re` module to use:

```
>>> r'xMain \2\1\3'
'xMain \\2\\1\\3'
```

The alternative would be to double the backslashes, escaping the escape:

```
b = re.sub('^xMain (\S+)/y1,/y0 (\S+ )(.*)$', 'xMain \\2\\1\\3', a)
```

Either way, your replacement pattern now works as expected:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'xMain Buchan/y1,/y0 Angus Sub1'
>>> re.sub('^xMain (\S+)/y1,/y0 (\S+ )(.*)$', r'xMain \2\1\3', a)
'xMain Angus BuchanSub1'
```